# Confused about elements of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is an exercise from [this book](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_intro-sets.html).

> Suppose that $$A \in B$$ and $$B \in C$$ . Does this mean that $$A \in C$$ ?
> Give an example to prove that this does NOT always happen (and explain
> why your example works). You should be able to give an example where
> $$|A| = |B| = |C| = 2$$ .

I could not find an example of 3 sets proving this statement. With my beginner understanding of sets, I think this cannot happen. If the set $b$ is an element of the set $c$ , then the elements of $b$ can never be related to $c$ because $b$ is not a subset of $c$. So $a$ cannot possibly be an element of $c$.

However, from the wording of the question (prove this does NOT always happen), this implies that the statement is usually true but there are cases where this is false. Can anyone help me think of an example where this statement is true or false?

Comment: The issue is that with "real life" examples it is not easy to make a difference between $\in$ and $\subseteq$: John lives in New York and thus we can say that $J \in NY$ and New York is a city of US; thus, $J \in US$. But, in terms of population, we have that New York is more correctly described as a *subset* of US.

Comment: Mathematical set theory is a ... mathematical theory, and thus it deals with mathematical objects, like set of numbers, functions, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *can* happen that $A\in B$, $B\in C$ and $A\in C$.

Take $A=\emptyset$. In order to have $A\in B$, the minimum requirement is $B=\{\emptyset\}$. In order to have $A\in C$ and $B\in C$, the minimum requirement is that $C=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

On the other hand, if you take $A=\emptyset$, $B=\{\emptyset\}$ and $C=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ you have $A\in B$, $B\in C$, but $A\notin C$, because the only element of $C$ is not the empty set.

Now try out an example with $|A|=|B|=|C|=2$. Hint: take for $A$ your favorite two-element set; then you want $B=\{A,u\}$ where $u\ne A$ and $C=\{B,v\}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Well, if $V \neq A$ , then the example will be false. If $V \= A$ then the example would be true. Is it correct?

Comment: @lightning_missile Yes, if you mean $v$ instead of $V$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I mean $V$ . Sorry I am using a screen reader and forgot to check the case.

Answer (score 7):

1. Consider $B=\{A\}$ and $C=\{B\}=\{ \{A\}\}$, then $A\in B, B\in C$ but $A\notin C$.
2. Consider $B=\{A\}$ and $C=\{B, A\}=\{A, \{A\}\}$, then $A\in B, B\in C$ and $A\in C$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want $|A| = |B| = |C| = 2$ then, using $D,E,F,G$ unrelated to each other, you can have $A \in C$ or not as you wish

1. Let $A=\{D,E\}$ and $B=\{A,F\}$ and $C=\{A,B\}$.
   Then $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ and $A \in C$
2. Let $A=\{D,E\}$ and $B=\{A,F\}$ and $C=\{B,G\}$.
   Then $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ but $A\not \in C$, since $A \not= B$ and $A\not =G$

I would say in a handwaving way that the second case might be seen as more usual than the first

Comment: @Hentry "the second case might be seen as more usual than the first" - this is exactly the reason I became confused. The second case is a lot easier to do than the first case, the wording in the question "does not always happens" implies otherwise, so I try looking at different answers.